# unable to get the latest record inserted in a table from frontend

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the latest inserted record from my table. I have just created a rule from front end and it created a rule id which is unique. Now the problem is that when i am trying to fetch the latest rule id created from the table i am not able to get the latest one that is created.

The latest one created is 4676, but when I try to query I get 4675. I am executing below queries. Is there anyway I can find the latest record by index of the table, as when I do max it bring 915 something as 9 is a bigger number than 4.

```
select * from mstcatrule where idrule = '4676'
select * from mstcatrule where rowid in (select max(rowid) from mstcatrule)
SELECT *
FROM (select * from mstcatrule ORDER BY rowid DESC) mstcatrule
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY rownum;
```

This are the queries I am executing.

Comment: Do you want the record most recently inserted *by any session* or just the record most recently inserted *by this session*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good thing that you are storing numbers in a VARCHAR field.  However, if you are just looking for the row with the highest idrule, and that field really is all numbers, you can do something like:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from mstcatrule
  order by to_number(idrule) desc nulls last
)
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for the Query. My problem is solved now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ROWID is not growing with time. So you can rely on MAX. In addition to that you should remember that database is multiuser system, so someone else can insert after your insert. So solutions based of surrogate id taken from a sequence will not help neither.
I can suggest to use `returning` clause:

```
insert into my_table(...)
values(...)
returning rowid into l_rowid;
```

then you can:

```
select * from my_table
where rowid = l_rowid;
```

But this works only in PL/SQL, so you probably need to write procedure to wrap your inserts.

Another way is to create after insert for each row trigger on this table which will be saving rowid into package global variable. And you can always get ROWID of the last inserted in your session row.